# Assembly: Multiply with 2 (shl)

Tags: assembly, x86-16, dos

Why does the result is space?(32) instead of ◘?(8)

```
mov    dl, 4        ;dl=00000100=4
shl    dl, 1        ;dl=00001000=8
mov    ah, 2
int    21h
```

What changes should I make to see the expected result?

Comment: How do you know it's a space?

Comment: `8` is a non standard printing character. It may even be interpreted by a terminal as *backspace*.

Comment: oh thanks, now i get it :)

Comment: If you want to see all the extended ASCII graphical glyphs of VGA, write them directly into VRAM (`B800:0000`) on your own. DOS is cherry-picking what is displayed and how.

Comment: There is no point in applying MOV+SHL to a constant value. Just do the shift at compile time, and move the result directly into DL. `mov  dl, 8`, or `mov  dl, 4 * 2` if you prefer.

Answer (score 3):

DOS is interpreting the ASCII codes that you provide with this function call. Since the value 8 represents a backspace, that is what DOS will do.

> What changes should I make to see the expected result?

Use the video BIOS function 0Ah, `WriteCharacterAtCursor`.

```
mov    cx, 1        ; Replication count
mov    bh, 0        ; Display page
mov    al, 8        ; Character code (00000100 << 1 == 00001000)
mov    ah, 0Ah      ; Function number
int    10h          ; Call the video BIOS interrupt
```